# Scheme how to check if a given parameter is number

Tags: integer, scheme

I need to check if a given parameter to function is integer or not but failed in some cases.

```
(integer? 10) returns #t
(integer? -) returns #f
(integer? "a") returns #f
```

These are working as expected but in this case, it is troublesome.

```
 (integer? a) returns 
  a: undefined;
  ;  cannot reference an identifier before its definition
  ;   in module: top-level
  ; [,bt for context]
```

I just want to check if given parameter is integer or not regardless of what is given; list, integer, double, char, anyting.

Comment: `integer?` will work for any type - the error you're receiving means that you didn't define `a` before referencing it. Define it first and it'll work.

Comment: What would "working as expected" be in the troublesome case?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `a` has not yet been defined, and `integer?` can't determine the type of an undefined variable.